# How to change the frequency scaling driver from "intel-pstate" to "acpi-cpufreq" or "p4-clockmod"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to change the current driver for `cpufreq-*` command to control CPU frequency on Intel NUC. The current driver is `intel-pstate` which allows `performance` and `powersave` only as governors.

```
$ cpufreq-info --driver
intel_pstate
$ cpufreq-info --governors
performance powersave
```

The `intel-pstate` driver does not have `userspace` as governor, which allows fixing the CPU Frequency. So, I want to change the driver for the `cpufreq-*` command.

I checked the available drivers and inserted the `p4-clockmod` driver:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/
amd_freq_sensitivity.ko  p4-clockmod.ko  speedstep-lib.ko
$ sudo modprobe p4-clockmod
```

However, the driver for `cpufreq-info` is still `intel-pstate`.

```
$ cpufreq-info --driver
intel_pstate
```

Please tell me how to change the driver for `cpufreq-*` command.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it like this:

1. Load the correct module:

   ```
    sudo modprobe p4-clockmod
   ```
2. Disable the `intel-pstate` driver:

   ```
    echo off | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
   ```
3. Activate the new driver:

   ```
    echo p4-clockmod | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
   ```

The above might not be possible if `intel-pstate` is enabled with HWP support (turning that off requires a reboot with kernel command line parameter `intel_pstate=no_hwp` *if I recall correctly*, [more info here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html#global-attributes)).

---

If you want to make things permanent, you'll have to change your kernel command line parameters:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, you should add `intel_pstate=disable` and `p4-clockmod`, so it should look like this:

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... intel_pstate=disable p4-clockmod"
   ```
2. Update the grub configuration:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
    # or 
    sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
3. Reboot and check that the module is loaded with `lsmod`.

---

Also note that this does not just "change the driver for the `cpufreq-*` commands". This changes the system-wide frequency scaling driver, the `cpufreq-*` commands just work with whatever driver is currently used.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful. I can disable "intel-pstate". However, the driver for cpufreq-* commands is "acpi-cpufreq". Can I disable "acpi-cpufreq" driver? I added "acpi-cpufreq=disable" as the Kernel parameter, but it does not work well.

Comment: I also tried to change the "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver", but it is read-only. Even if I add write permission, it does not work well.

Comment: Maybe it's `acpi_cpufreq=disable`, by the way you can try `modprobe -r acpi-cpufreq` or even [blacklist the module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules). If `scaling_driver` is read only you cannot magically make it writable, it's not a real file. I don't know much more about `p4-clockmod` to be of further unfortunately.

Comment: I confirmed that "acpi-cpufreq" driver has the "userspace" governor and I could fix the CPU frequency with "cpufreq-set -f 1000Mhz". Unfortunately, the CPU frequency goes to 700-600Mhz. It works just upper-limit.

Comment: @KuniyasuSuzaki you might want to check `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`.

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` is 1501000

Comment: Well that's a different problem anyway. It's hard to tell what could be the reason for it based on the limited information you provide unfortunately. You could try asking at [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `$ sudo modprobe -r acpi-cpufreq
modprobe: FATAL: Module acpi_cpufreq is builtin.`
Oh, I can not remove the driver. I use Ubuntu1804.
`$ uname -a
Linux suzaki-NUC7PJYH 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I could fix `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` wiht 1000000 using `$ sudo cpupower frequency-set -g userspace -u 1000M -d 1000M`.   However, the CPU frequency goes to 700-600Mhz on `/proc/cpuinfo`.